# Prove for any function: $f:\:A\rightarrow B$ and any sets $C,D\subseteq A$, $f\left(C\right)$ ∖ $f\left(D\right) \subseteq f(C\backslash D) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

My thinking:

Let $x\in f\left(C\right)∖f\left(D\right)$

= $x\in f\left(C\right)$ and $x\notin f\left(D\right)$

If $x\in f\left(C\right)$, $\exists \:x_1\in C$ such that $f\left(x_1\right)=x$

If $x\notin f\left(D\right)$, $∄ \:x_2\in D$ such that $ f\left(x_2\right)=x$

I don't know where to go from here, can someone please provide a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in f\left(C\right)\setminus f\left(D\right)$

Then, $x\in f\left(C\right)$ and $x\notin f\left(D\right). $

Let $x_1$ be such that $f(x_1) = x.$

Then, $x_1\in C,\ $ but $\ x_1 \notin D,$ and so $x_1 \in C\setminus D.$

Therefore, $f(x_1)$...

Comment: Therefore, $f(x_1)\in f(C∖D)$ since $x_1 \in C∖D$?

Comment: Exactly right! .

Answer (score 0):

The second statement should be written as $\forall x_2 \in D$, $f(x_2)\neq x$. So, if $x_1 \in C$ and $f(x_1)=x$, then $x\not \in D$.

Combining both statements,

$\exists x_{1}\in C $ and $x_1\not \in D$ such that $f(x_1)=x$.

$\exists x_{1}\in C\setminus D$ such that $f(x_1)=x$. It implies that $x\in f(C \setminus D)$.